# SQL Alchemy insert no parameters supplied

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, parameters, sqlalchemy

**I am trying** to insert values to SQL Server database using SQL Alchemy (?,?,?) syntax for supplying parameters. I am encountering two issues.

```
python = "3.10.2"
SQLAlchemy = "^1.4.32"
pyodbc = "^4.0.32"

SQL Server drivers = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

# Connection is made with this string
conn_params = server, database, uid, pwd
con_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" + "SERVER={};"
            "DATABASE={};"
            "UID={};"
            "PWD={}".format(*conn_params)

# engine is created with
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    url="mssql+pyodbc://",
    creator=pyodbc.connect(con_string),
    echo=False,
    fast_executemany=True,
)

table for testing:
CREATE TABLE testing (
   id INT,
   name NVARCHAR(255)
);
```

**1st Issue:**
*'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'* error is thrown when executed following

```
query = sqlalchemy.sql.text('INSERT INTO testing (id,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)')
insert_values = [
            [3, "a"],
            [3, "f"],
            [3, "e"],
            [3, "d"],
            [3, "c"],
            [3, "b"]
        ]
with engine.connect() as con:
            con.execute(
                query,
                *insert_values
            )
```

I can't figure at which point it makes this comparison and fails (and why it does it?). My `id` field is defined as INT so it doesn't make sense to convert to string. For sake of tries and errors I did it anyway. Then occurs:

**2nd Issue** *(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Expected 6 parameters, supplied 0', 'HY000')
[SQL: INSERT INTO testing (id,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)]
[parameters: ((), (), (), (), (), ())]*

Exact same code as above but with ids converted to strings

```
insert_values=[
    ["3", "a"],
    ["3", "f"],
    ["3", "e"],
    ["3", "d"],
    ["3", "c"],
    ["3", "b"],
]
```

According to [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) on supplying **multiparamater* it seems to me that I am doing it correctly. Apparently I don't

I know that I can supply **kwargs arguments but would rather like to go with *args

Comment: `VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)` suggests you are inserting in 6 columns, but (`INSERT INTO testing (id,name)`) you really only seem to want 2

Comment: Thanks for answer. After changing query to ```VALUES (?, ?)``` I still get ```(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Expected 2 parameters, supplied 0', 'HY000')```

Comment: The SQLAlchemy documentation you link to mentions tuples, not lists, so have you tried `( ("3", "a"), ("3", "f"), ("3", "e"), ("3", "d"), ("3", "c"), ("3", "b") )` yet?

Comment: Yep I did. Same results

Answer (score 0):

I found an explanation to it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_core_using_textual_sql.htm)

btw. [HoneyBadger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587819/honeybadger) made a valid point that number of "?" in `VALUES (?, ?, ?)` should be equal to number of columns I am inserting to, not number of rows I am inserting

> *The text()function requires Bound parameters in the named colon format. They are consistent regardless of database backend*

So (?) syntax for supplying parameters is not available with `TextClause`

It can be done it on string though. Following code inserts data as expected:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO testing (id,name) VALUES (?,?)'  # Changed to string and reduces no. '?'
insert_values = [
            [3, "a"],
            [3, "f"],
            [3, "e"],
            [3, "d"],
            [3, "c"],
            [3, "b"]
        ]
with engine.connect() as con:
            con.execute(
                query,
                *insert_values
            )
```